# using jquery to change contents of form upon typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to get the default value to not go away on click, but rather when the user starts typing (so they know what the field is for)....the problem is the following:

when I use onchange instead of onfocus it keeps the default value in there when they start typing. If its confusing what I am doing go to facebook and look how their search box works...thats what I am going for.

```
<script>

    function uFocus() {
        $('#fakeusername').hide();
        $('#username').show();
        $('#username').focus();
    }

    function uBlur() {
        if ($('#username').attr('value') == '') {
            $('#username').hide();
            $('#fakeusername').show();
        }
    }
</script>
<input style='width:202px;height:25px;margin-top:8px;font-size:14px;color:gray;' type='text'  name='fakeusername' id='fakeusername' value='  Username' onfocus='uFocus()' />
<input style='width:202px;height:25px;margin-top:8px;font-size:14px;color:#000000;display: none' type='text' name='username' id='username' value='' onblur='uBlur()' />
```

Comment: I like this idea. It's easy to click on something, become distracted, and then forget what you were supposed to type. Or forget the suggested format (phone number with dashes or not?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

In HTML5, the `placeholder` attribute will simulate what you want with no Javascript needed.

```
<input type='text'  name='fakeusername' id='fakeusername' value='Username' placeholder='Type your username' />
```

The second, and I believe the approach used by Facebook, is to swap a background image containing the sample text with a blank one. So you might create two background images (the first containing the words "Type your username" in the font used by the input, the second a blank) and set them to flip whenever the input is focused.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
$("#fakeusername").on({
    focus: function() {
        $(this).css('color', '#000');
    },
    blur: function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'grey');
    },
    keydown: function() {
        if ($(this).val()=='  Username') {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/Y58ML/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that places label over top of input and requires proper `for/ID` match to allow browser to do default focus of input when clicking on label. Positions label over top of input, if no value of input on blur will show label again. Using label makes it accessible

http://jsfiddle.net/UCxaZ/2